# zsh autocomplete slow for ssh

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, macos-catalina

I upgraded my macbook to OSX Catalina recently. Ever since that upgrade my zsh autocomplete (tab completion) for ssh is really slow (previously, it was reasonably fast, e.g. autocomplete would happen in a few seconds). Some details that I think are relevant:

1. I have a `~/.ssh/config` file with ~2000 hosts configured
2. When I type `ssh x <TAB>` things seem to hang, typing ctrl-C says `Killed by signal in _ssh_hosts after 22s` so it seems that my `_ssh_hosts` script is the problem

Any tips on how to debug this? Or alternate `_ssh_hosts` function I could use?

Comment: The autocompletion for `ssh` reparses your config file every time, rather than caching the results in memory the first time.

Comment: I wrote up an answer for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59713037/1126841) that refactors your `ssh` file into multiple files, one per host. That's probably less helpful for you, as 2000 individual host-specific config files may present its own problem.

Answer (score 9):

I've put together a solution that works for me using `zstyle` thanks to [this email thread](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2018/msg00142.html)

My solution was to make my `~/.zshrc` contain the following

```
function refresh_ssh_autocomplete () {
    host_list=($(cat ~/.ssh/config | grep 'Host '  | awk '{s = s $2 " "} END {print s}'))
    zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|sftp):*' hosts $host_list
}
refresh_ssh_autocomplete
```